# Using BeautifulSoup to Web Scrape Tags with CSS IDs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-analysis

I am trying to webscrape this website for a  tag that has the id = '2004.advanced' (which exists). These are the three lines of code I tried.

```
webpage = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all( attrs = {'id': 'advanced.2004'}))
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the element you're trying to find is inside a comment. To workaround this, try looping through every comment on the page, parsing it's content using `BeautifulSoup` and searching for the element you want:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html'
webpage = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')

for comment in soup.find_all(text=lambda el:isinstance(el, Comment)):
    comment_html = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'html.parser')
    el = comment_html.find(id='advanced.2004')

    if el != None: break

print(el)
```

Comment: How did you know that the element was inside a comment? I couldn't tell when I inspected the website.

Comment: @DapperL i checked the page source code using ctrl+u on firefox, but you're right, when inspecting the website the element is actually not inside a comment. my guess is that it's that the comment is removed using javascript after the page is loaded, but since we're using `requests.get` that javascript is never executed.

Comment: @DapperL if this answer solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419). This indicates that you've found a solution, and awards some reputation to both you and the answerer. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).